# How can I beat the True Final Boss of Hitogata Happa?

Tags: hitogata-happa

The True Final Boss of Hitogata Happa is the one part I have extreme difficulty with even on Euridice (easy) difficulty. Is there some strategy or set of dolls I can use that perform better on her?

The "dolls" part of the fight I understand but I still die a lot on. Does she have a set amount of each doll, or are the dolls she brings out different every time? For instance, if I find one doll really hard to fight, can I wait till she uses an easier doll and just kill those?

Does the damage you deal to the boss while her dolls are alive actually matter? It seems like her health drains very slowly, should I completely ignore her and only hit the dolls? I always find myself **running out of time** in the final part of the fight, so whatever I can do to end either stage quicker helps.

I also noticed she uses the same bullet patterns repeatedly and you HAVE to dodge all of them to catch a break; is there some strategy to each? I specifically get stuck on the "grid" pattern of bullets, I find it very hard to know where a safe place will be.

> How do I beat Kreutzer?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Gamefaqs faq [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/933627-hitogata-happa/faqs/44538), you need to focus on the dolls.

> From Gamefaqs: Kreutzer has many attacks each one is very difficult to avoid. Anyway to win its not
>  to damage her its actually to exhaust her doll supply. This can be done by
>  destroying the dolls. Do it quickly though otherwise you'll run out of time and that
>  won't be good.

Also...

> From Gamefaqs: She also has 8 attacks she'll do inbetween each doll barrage. The first one
>  she'll summon large bullets moving around in a circle. This is really easy to avoid
>  just watch out for any stray bullets she'll make. The second one she'll shoot bullet
>  waves, this one is easy to avoid too. The third one she'll rush to one side of the
>  screen while bullets coming from that side will rush to other, fairly tricky to
>  avoid. The next one is one of her hardest, she summon bullet circles which shoot
>  bullet waves at you, this tricky to avoid even in Euridice. The next one she'll rush
>  back and forth creating bullet circles which can be tricky to avoid. Her next one
>  she creates a grid of bullets, this one is pretty tough too. I haven't got her last
>  two ones down yet.

Here is a video of the fight, which will probably better show how to deal with each bullet pattern.

> !

Comment: That's only the first  half of the fight, the second half the Dolls are all gone and she focuses on bullet patterns, which I'm having trouble with

Comment: I keyed off your comment: "Does the damage you deal to the boss while her dolls are alive actually matter?" That said, each bullet pattern is detailed in the FAQ.  I hesitate to post it all because it is lengthy and I didn't write it.  I'll link a YouTube video though.  Seems I don't know how to "spoiler-proof" it - if that's even possible with embedded videos.